# 3 simple/basic limit math problems

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I ended in IT uni in my country. My classes are not regular. For every semester I go to uni one full month(I have lectures every day of the month). In the rest of the time I have to study alone and I can go to work more easier. Anyway, in high school I have barely touch math. Now I have started to catch up on my own, but its hard and slow. I can't reach that fast the math level in my classes so I need your help from the internet. I want you to help me with part of my homework.

Limits

1. $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^{6x} $$

I think the answer is $u^6 $ but I have no idea.

2. $$\lim_{x\to -2||-2\to x} \frac{5}{x+2} $$

I don't know how to write the 2 limits one under the other.

3. $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{4}{x+1} $$

If someone could give me step by step answer that I could write as homework, I would be so happy. I know that Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. What is $u$?

2. What does it mean to have $-2 \to x$?

3. Think about what happens to the denominator as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: For the first problem, I'm not sure where you got $u$ from. Perhaps you mean $e = 2.718...$?

Comment: If someone gave you a step-by-step-step answer, and you wrote it as homework, wouldn't you be cheating? Doesn't your uni have a rule against that?

Answer (score 1):

This addresses general limits with rational functions of polynomials, like  $\#3$ which ends up being quite simple. For this you have to understand the degree of a polynomial. $x^2 + x + 1$ has a degree of $2$ because that is the highest exponent. Similarly $x^{798} + 4$ has a degree of $798$

There are only three cases for rational functions with polynomials.

1)The degree on the numerator is higher than that of the denominator.

In this case, as $x \to \infty$, the numerator will be waaaaaaay higher than the denominator, so the limit will be $\infty$, or it doesn't exist.

2)The degree on the numerator is the same as that of the denominator.

Let's try an example: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{432} + x^{243}+4}{2x^{432} + x^{74} + 78}$.

The way this works is that the term with the highest degree will be the only one that matters. All the others will be too small in comparison to the largest degree. Therefore, we only look at the coefficient for the terms with the largest degree. In the example above, the coefficients are $1$ and $2$, so the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.

3) The degree on the numerator is smaller than the degree on the denominator.

This is basically the opposite of case 1. Instead of the numerator being waaaaay larger than the denominator, the denominator will be far larger than the numerator, which means that as $x \to \infty$, the limit will be $0$.

Comment: I believe your answer for (1) is incorrect. The correct answer should be $e^6$. Perhaps you overlooked the fact that $x$ was in the exponent?

Comment: Are you talking to me? Because I didn't answer number 1.

Comment: Whoops! I thought your 3 cases were answers to the 3 questions.